# Source in .sh script does not work after opening new terminal from .sh script

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, alias

I have a problem with sourcing aliases. It's really specific case. I open new terminal window with two tabs using open_new.sh:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    gnome-terminal --tab --title="Tab1" -e "./tab1.sh" --tab --title="Tab2" -e "./tab2.sh"
```

In file tab1.sh i have:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    ls
    . ~/.my_aliases
    echo "done"
    exec bash
```

File tab2.sh looks very similar. Line 2 and 4 works fine but it looks like line 3 does not work. When I try to use 'lll' alias it says 'bash: lll: command not found'. Then when I type command from line 3 directly in terminal aliases start working.

I have tried many different solution but I still can't handle it. For example I've tried something like this before sourcing:

```
    shopt -s expand_aliases
```

I've tried this:

```
    source ~/.my_aliases
```

And also I've tried:

```
    #!/bin/bash -i
```

Is someone able to help me?
Maybe I should mention two things: I am not root user, I don't have any problems with sourcing that file with aliases in normal way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need `exec bash` in tab1.sh?  That seems like the issue.

Comment: If i don't add 'exec bash', I will not be able to type anything when tab1.sh finish executing.

Comment: `exec` replaces the current shell with a new process. The fact that that new process is also a shell doesn't mean aliases are transferred to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking for answer for three days before I asked question here. And now I've found the answer that I want to share if someone else will struggle with this problem in the future. In file open_new.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --tab --title="Tab1" -e "bash --rcfile ./tab1.sh" --tab --title="Tab2" -e "bash --rcfile ./tab2.sh"
```

In file tab1.sh:

```
. ~/.bashrc
. ~/.my_aliases
ls
echo "done"
```

Explanation:

```
--rcfile File #execute commands from File instead of the standard personal initialization file ~/.bashrc
```

In File you can place many other commands. All bash commands worked for me. I've found solution in:

```
man bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest appending the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

`source ~/.my_aliases`

This way, all new tabs will inherit your aliases.

Comment: I am not able to edit this file because I am not root user.

Comment: as you might have figured out already, `exec bash` spawns a new bash process, that does not inherit the formerly loaded aliases

Comment: also, `.bashrc` is a user configuration file, so you should have editing permissions under normal conditions. It's in your home dir, after all! Regardless, you can also use `~/.bash_aliases` - it will have the same effect.

Comment: I agree. Under normal conditions I should have editing permission. But this is my company environment and unfortunately I don't have them. Thanks for pointing what exactly `exec bash` does. I didn't knew that.

Comment: Now I think that I should just find good replacement for that command. Can you suggest me something?

Comment: Sorry for repeating: if you can create `~/.my_aliases`, then can you also create `~/.bash_aliases`? The latter is a standard file that always gets loaded by newly created `bash` processes.

Comment: Yes, I can create `~/.bash_aliases`. And I've tried to use it, but it does not added any aliases in new `bash` process.